# Mat file saving with different names

Tags: matlab, variables

I am running lots of algorithms. I have changed my codes in terms of reducing the time. I am just changing the imagefilename and maskfile name. I want to save the results corresponding file name: matlabfilename. Here is the codes;

```
imagefilename='lena_gray_256.tif';
maskfilename='M1.tif';
matlabfilename=[imagefilename maskfilename];
filename = ['Masks_' imagefilename maskfilename];
filename2 =['Results_' imagefilename maskfilename];

...
There are some algortihms here. 
...

%Save the figure
saveas( gcf, filename, 'jpg' );
saveas( gcf, filename2, 'jpg' );
save (matlabfilename)
```

So matlabfilename is lena_gray_256.tifM1.tif

The problem is on the last line. I want to record the results as 
lena_gray_256.tifM1.tif.mat but I could not find the exact definition.

Can anybody improve?

Thanks

Comment: It was the results of the Neural Network algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to add .mat to the end of your string, this should work:

```
save ([matlabfilename,'.mat'])
```

Comment: Great, glad I could help! Please select it as an answer using the green check mark so others know. Thanks!